# How to convert partial dates in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 date columns in 2 diff tables that I need to compare, both varchar2 type. Both columns have partial and full dates based on the data.

T1:

```
ID    Partial_date1  
1     19-DEC-2016  
2     06-MAY-2015  
3     2016  
4  
5     AUG-2016  
6     16-NOV-2015 00:00  
7     01-JAN-2016
```

T2:

```
ID     Partial_date2  
1     09-JAN-2016  
2     2016  
3     SEP-2015  
4   
5     23-MAR-2016 00:00  
6     15-MAY-2015  
7
```

I want to search for all records that have full dates (as it is not possible to convert partial dates), to select only the records with full dates, I have used length >10. Here is the SQL I wrote but does not seem to be working.

```
select t1.id from t1, t2
where t1.id =t2.id
and length(t1.partial_date1)>10
and length(t2.partial_date2)>10
and to_date(t1.partial_date1,'DD-MON-YYYY') > to_date(t2.partial_date2,'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

I either get an error - ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
or literal does not match format string.

What am I doing wrong? how do I get the right results?

Comment: Did you mean to take `SUBSTR(t1.partial_date1, 10)` before passing to `TO_DATE`, and the same for the RHS?

Comment: You don't have dates, you have varchar2 representing dates.  That is never a good thing.  Please show the sample data.

Comment: I do not need to take the substring, I only want to pick the records with full dates for comparison since we cannot convert partial dates.

Comment: You can't take the string `'23-MAR-2015 10:00:00'` and convert it to a date with `to_date()` with the format model `'DD-MON-YYYY'`, that's not how `to_date()` works. If you want to convert the full string to a FULL date, you need to use a full format model.

Comment: True or False: all the strings in the columns are in exactly one of two formats, either 'DD-MON-YYYY' or 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'. (Or some other full format, but THE SAME for all the strings that have a FULL date.)  If this is FALSE, then I don't think you'll be able to write anything meaningful. If it is TRUE, just use the appropriate FULL format model in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @mathguy : I added Sample data.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: I added Sample data

Comment: How do you define "full date"? No less than `'DD-MON-YYYY'`? Then you should use the length condition you have, and - if you just want to compare by date, not by time-of-day - then use substr(..., 11) (I said 10 earlier but I was wrong, you want 11 because you have MON, not MM for month).

Comment: full date is DD-MON-YYYY not including time.

Answer (score 0):

When you write condition in where clause oracle may use it as access predicate. And it function `to_date(t1.partial_date1,'DD-MON-YYYY')` is used to any row.

That's why you get an error.

I see two ways:

First way is use a subquery to get a shrunk dataset, substr only 10 symbols and then convert it

```
with t1(id,partial_date1) as 
(
    select 1,'19-DEC-2016' from dual union all
    select 2,'06-MAY-2015' from dual union all
    select 3, '2016' from dual union all
    select 4,'' from dual union all
    select 5,'AUG-2016' from dual union all
    select 6,'16-NOV-2015 00:00' from dual union all
    select 7, '01-JAN-2016' from dual
), t2(id,partial_date2) as 
(
    select 1,'09-JAN-2016' from dual union all
    select 2,'2016' from dual union all
    select 3,'SEP-2015' from dual union all
    select 4,'' from dual union all
    select 5,'23-MAR-2016 00:00' from dual union all
    select 6,'15-MAY-2015' from dual union all
    select 7,'' from dual
)
select * 
from 
    (select 
         t1.id,
         partial_date1,
         partial_date2
     from 
         t1, t2
     where 
         t1.id =t2.id
         and length(t1.partial_date1) > 10
         and length(t2.partial_date2) > 10
         and rownum > 0)
where 
    to_date(substr(partial_date1,1,10),'DD-MON-YYYY') > to_date(substr(partial_date2,1,10),'DD-MON-YYYY');
/
```

The second way is to explicitly convert any format to properly one

```
with t1(id,partial_date1) as (
select 1,'19-DEC-2016' from dual union all
select 2,'06-MAY-2015' from dual union all
select 3, '2016' from dual union all
select 4,'' from dual union all
select 5,'AUG-2016' from dual union all
select 6,'16-NOV-2015 00:00' from dual union all
select 7, '01-JAN-2016' from dual)
,t2(id,partial_date2) as (
select 1,'09-JAN-2016' from dual union all
select 2,'2016' from dual union all
select 3,'SEP-2015' from dual union all
select 4,'' from dual union all
select 5,'23-MAR-2016 00:00' from dual union all
select 6,'15-MAY-2015' from dual union all
select 7,'' from dual)
select * from( 
select t1.id,
      case
          when regexp_like(t1.partial_date1,'\d{1,2}-\w{3}-\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}') then to_date(t1.partial_date1,'dd-MON-yyyy HH24:MI')
          when regexp_like(t1.partial_date1,'\d{1,2}-\w{3}-\d{4}') then to_date(t1.partial_date1,'dd-MON-yyyy')
          when regexp_like(t1.partial_date1,'\w{3}-\d{4}') then to_date(t1.partial_date1,'MON-yyyy')
          when regexp_like(t1.partial_date1,'\d{4}') then to_date(t1.partial_date1,'yyyy')
      end as pd1,
      case
          when regexp_like(t2.partial_date2,'\d{1,2}-\w{3}-\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}') then to_date(t2.partial_date2,'dd-MON-yyyy HH24:MI')
          when regexp_like(t2.partial_date2,'\d{1,2}-\w{3}-\d{4}') then to_date(t2.partial_date2,'dd-MON-yyyy')
          when regexp_like(t2.partial_date2,'\w{3}-\d{4}') then to_date(t2.partial_date2,'MON-yyyy')
          when regexp_like(t2.partial_date2,'\d{4}') then to_date(t2.partial_date2,'yyyy')
      end as pd2
from t1,t2
where t1.id = t2.id)
where pd1 > pd2
/
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you consider a date complete when the string starts with DD-MMM-YYYY. You can use `REGEXP_LIKE` to find such rows:

```
where regexp_like(partial_date, '^[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:upper:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{4}')
```

(You may want to adjust the pattern according to your needs, e.g. replace `[[:upper:]]` with `[[:alpha:]]`.)

In order to convert a date containing a textual month you should use `TO_DATE` with a language parameter:

```
to_date(partial_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
```

A possible query:

```
select tt1.id 
from 
(
  select
    id,
    to_date(substr(partial_date1, 1, 11), 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
      as dt
  from t1
  where regexp_like(partial_date1, '^[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:upper:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{4}')
) tt1
join 
(
  select
    id,
    to_date(substr(partial_date2, 1, 11), 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
      as dt
  from t2
  where regexp_like(partial_date2, '^[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:upper:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{4}')
) tt2 on tt2.id = tt1.id and tt2.dt < tt1.dt;
```

However, keep in mind that you are still dealing with strings. Conversion on "dates" like these would fail and crash your query:

- 30-FEB-2017
- 01-YAN-2017
- 99-XXX-9999

So depending on the data quality your best bet may be to write a PL/SQL function in order to catch conversion errors.

Answer (score -2):

```
case
            when PurchaseDate = '0' then NULL
            when right(PurchaseDate, 4) = '0000' then convert(date, left(PurchaseDate,4) + '1231', 112)
            when RIGHT(PurchaseDate, 2) = '00' then DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month,cast(left(RIGHT(Purchasedate,4),2) AS INT),DATEADD(year,cast(LEFT(Purchasedate, 4) AS int)-1900,0)))
            else convert(date, ltrim(rtrim(cast(PurchaseDate as varchar(50)))), 112)
            end
```

Apologize. This is from my phone. This does a few things. It assumes different formats plus it counters for missing days and months.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It can't help. The post is clearly tagged Oracle. There are no LEFT and RIGHT and DATEADD functions in Oracle. The tags are there for a reason. -1 for that reason.

Comment: I did say I was working from my phone. :D  replace right with the oracle version: SUBSTR(PurchaseDate, -1, 2).  for dateadd, just use plus(+) and minus(-)